# Replacing variables in BASH with user input

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am hoping someone can help me with some text manipulation, it's not my strong point and I'm coming up against an issue when trying to replace text in a file.

I have a Terraform file, what I wish to do is run a BASH script which collects user input and fills in the Terraform file. The format is as follows:

**Terraform.tf**

```
variable "master_cpu" {default = }
variable "master_mem" {default = }
variable "master_count" {default = }
variable "master_template" {default = ""}
variable "master_datastore" {default = ""}
variable "master_secondary_disk_size" {default = }
variable "master_network_label" {default = ""}
variable "master_gateway" {default = ""}
variable "master_netmask" {default = ""}
```

**Provisioner.sh**

```
echo -n "How many vCPU's should these VM's have? [ENTER]:"
read master_cpu
echo -n "How much RAM would you like to allocate? [ENTER]:"
read master_ram
echo -n "Template name? Format: Folder/template [ENTER]:"
read master_template
echo -n "Please provide the datastore name. [ENTER]:"
read master_dstore
...
```

There are 2 issues here, first one is numbers aren't wrapped in double quotes but text is, so simply searching for *default = ""* in the Terraform file is of no use.

The other issue I've faced is with variables not expanding, for example:

```
awk '{gsub("default = \"\"", "default = \"$vc_address\"", $0); print > FILENAME}' terraform.tf
```

Will produce: default = "$vc_address" and not use the IP captured on the command line.

If anyone could give me some pointers on how to efficiently do this in BASH, for both numbers and text I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question: why don't you let the user edit the terraform file directly? the user has to do something: either fill in your forms or edit the file… what's wrong with letting the user edit the file directly?

Comment: Well there are a whole bunch of other steps to take too, Terraform is the first part, then some Ansible playbooks after that. I'd like to reduce as much away from the person installing as possible, so they just input and go.

Comment: Ok… so you have to make sure that your script doesn't introduce other errors! and that can be tricky. Now, will the terraform file always have the same structure (same fields, etc.)? if it's the case, it would be wiser to generate the file from scratch with the input you collected, instead of trying to edit an existing one.

Comment: Yeah, the input fields will be fixed, there's nothing dynamic there. What's the best way in BASH though to generate the file from scratch each time without a whole bunch of echo "" statements?

Comment: You'll have to use `echo`s or `read -p` anyways, since you're prompting user for some input. Use, e.g., `read -rep "How many vCPU's should these VM's have? [ENTER]: " master_cpu`. After this: check that user really input a number, otherwise prompt again; in the case of a string, you'll have to handle double quotes (escape them or remove them)—and maybe also handle escape chars (I don't know whether terraform files use escape characters…).

Comment: After you collected the data and everything is fine, use a here-doc to generate your file.

Comment: I've taken your advice and generated the file from scratch, works very well. Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a template engine, and this can be achieved using bash here-doc:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "How many vCPU's should these VM's have? [ENTER]:"
read master_cpu
echo -n "How much RAM would you like to allocate? [ENTER]:"
read master_ram
echo -n "Template name? Format: Folder/template [ENTER]:"
read master_template
echo -n "Please provide the datastore name. [ENTER]:"
read master_dstore

# Use heredoc to generate the file, use EOF and not "EOF" since we want bash substitution
cat > Terraform.tf << EOF
variable "master_cpu" {default = $master_cpu}
variable "master_mem" {default = $master_ram}
variable "master_count" {default = }
variable "master_template" {default = ""}
variable "master_datastore" {default = ""}
variable "master_secondary_disk_size" {default = }
variable "master_network_label" {default = ""}
variable "master_gateway" {default = ""}
variable "master_netmask" {default = ""}
EOF
```

You can read more about heredoc here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

As for variables not expanding, there's a difference between ' and " in bash. Basically ' means literal (do not expand). See bash manual for:

- Single quotes: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html#Single-Quotes
- Double quotes: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html